# How do I manipulate inner html of element after clicking a button

Tags: jquery

Here I'm trying to select button whose class is add and then change its parent elements inner html to hello but this code dose not work for some reason can someone please guide me.

```
$(document).on('click','.add',()=>{ 
    $(this).parent().html('hello')
});
```

Comment: could you please provide your HTML code

Comment: @mohamedruzaik what for?

Comment: The link above is quite long, but worth understanding.  In summary, when you use `()=>` the `this` is isn't the `.add` that you clicked on, it's the same `this` as the outer scope (likely window/document).   Change from `()=>{` to `function() {` and your code will work.

Comment: @freedomn-m he is referring to a parent element which is unknown

Comment: @mohamedruzaik you mean `$(this).parent()`? The issue is with `()=>` so the `.add`'s parent is irrelevant as it's not `this`

Comment: Hmm.. seems like the arrow function doesn't have this with it parent must be changed

Comment: Yes, the link I provided explains all that.  Here's another one https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/1st-ed/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#not-just-shorter-syntax-but-this   In summary: don't use `()=>` for click event handlers

Comment: Thanks brother it worked